# How to make ag grid header sticky and responsive with resizing feature

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular6, ag-grid-angular

**Resolved:** (100 % working in chrome and edge) (in IE11, it works fine if there is no horizontal scroll in grid)

HTML:
gridAutoHeight = true in ag-grid-angular html tag

TS:
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll); in ngOnit()

```
scroll = (event: any): void => {
let headerElementRef;
let bodyElementRef;
headerElementRef = document.querySelector('[ref="headerRoot"]');
bodyElementRef = document.querySelector('[ref="eBodyViewport"]');
const nav = headerElementRef;
const body = bodyElementRef;
const offset = nav.getBoundingClientRect();
if (!nav) return;

  if (window.pageYOffset > offset.top && !(body.getBoundingClientRect().top - nav.getBoundingClientRect().height > 0)) {
    nav.style.position = 'fixed';
    nav.style.top = 0;
    nav.style.zIndex = "2";
    nav.style.width = this.totalGridWidth + 'px';
  } else {
    nav.style.position = 'relative';
    nav.style.top = '';
    nav.style.zIndex = "";
    nav.style.width = this.totalGridWidth + 'px';
  }
```

}

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Perhaps on stackblitz.com? Or codesandbox.io?

Comment: try removing `[gridAutoHeight] = "true"` Have look at this plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/U38afajrk1f57ZOlS4Ns?p=preview. First grid has fixed header where `gridAutoHeight` is removed except all other attributes from your snippet. Whereas second consists all the attributes.

Comment: @Nik : It is already sticky with the above CSS but it is not reponsive with the re-sizing feature of ag-grid. Removing the [gridAutoHeight] = "true" will not solve the problem.

Comment: What is the value of this.totalGridWidth you are using?

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <ag-grid-angular style="margin-top:10px; width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [pagination]="true" [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize" [enableColResize]="true" [paginationNumberFormatter]="paginationNumberFormatter" [enableSorting]="true" [enableFilter]="true" [headerHeight] = "headerHeight" [gridAutoHeight] = "true" [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate" [rowData]="gridData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" (columnResized)="onColumnResized($event)" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"> </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```